# Interpretation of a fundamental inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

How do you interpret $0 < \vert x-a\vert < d$ with algebra? (I understand what this means geometrically but am struggling to understand this through algebra.)

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value is defined as
$$\vert x\vert=
\begin{cases}
x, \quad\text{if } x\geq0\\
-x, \quad\text{if } x<0
\end{cases}
.$$
If you apply this definition to your inequality, you obtain two equations:
$$
0<x-a<d\quad\text{ for }x-a\geq0,\\0<-(x-a)<d\quad\text{ for }x-a<0
$$
Solving this leads to
$$a<x<d+a\;\vee\;a-d<x<a.$$
Note that the conditions $x-a\geq0$ respectively $x-a<0$ are implicitly contained in the final solution.